# Fastest way to (arg)sort a flattened nD-array that is sorted along each dimension?

Tags: arrays, sorting, language-agnostic

The question itself is language-agnostic. I will use python for my example, mainly because I think it is nice to demonstrate the point.

---

I have an N-dimensional array of shape `(n1, n2, ..., nN)` that is contiguous in memory (c-order) and filled with numbers. For each dimension by itself, the numbers are ordered in ascending order. A 2D example of such an array is:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> n1 = np.arange(5)[:, None]
>>> n2 = np.arange(7)[None, :]
>>> n1+n2
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

In this case, the values in each row are ascending, and the values in each column are ascending, too. A 1D example array is

```
>>> n1 = np.arange(10)
>>> n1*n1
array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81])
```

I would like to obtain a list/array containing the indices that would sort the flattened version of the nD array in ascending order. By the flattened array I mean that I interpret the nD-array as a 1D array of equivalent size. The sorting doesn't have to preserve order, i.e., the order of indices indexing equal numbers doesn't matter. For example

```
>>> n1 = np.arange(5)[:, None]
>>> n2 = np.arange(7)[None, :]
>>> arr = n1*n2
>>> arr
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12],
       [ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18],
       [ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16, 20, 24]])
>>> np.argsort(arr.ravel())
array([ 0, 28, 14,  7,  6, 21,  4,  3,  2,  1,  5,  8,  9, 15, 22, 10, 11,
       29, 16, 12, 23, 17, 13, 18, 30, 24, 19, 25, 31, 20, 26, 32, 27, 33,
       34], dtype=int64)
```

Standard sorting on the flattened array can accomplish this; however, it doesn't exploit the fact that the array is already partially sorted, so I suspect there exists a more efficient solution. **What is the most efficient way to do so?**

---

A comment asked what my use-case is, and if I could provide some more realistic test data for benchmarking. Here is how I encountered this problem:

> Given an image and a binary mask for that image (which selects pixels), find the largest sub-image which contains only selected pixels.

In my case, I applied a perspective transformation to an image, and want to crop it so that there is no black background while preserving as much of the image as possible.

```
from skimage import data
from skimage import transform
from skimage import img_as_float

tform = transform.EuclideanTransform(
    rotation=np.pi / 12.,
    translation = (10, -10)
    )

img = img_as_float(data.chelsea())[50:100, 150:200]
tf_img = transform.warp(img, tform.inverse)
tf_mask = transform.warp(np.ones_like(img), tform.inverse)[..., 0]

y = np.arange(tf_mask.shape[0])
x = np.arange(tf_mask.shape[1])
y1 = y[:, None, None, None]
y2 = y[None, None, :, None]
x1 = x[None, :, None, None]
x2 = x[None, None, None, :]

y_padded, x_padded = np.where(tf_mask==0.0)
y_padded = y_padded[None, None, None, None, :]
x_padded = x_padded[None, None, None, None, :]
y_inside = np.logical_and(y1[..., None] <= y_padded, y_padded<= y2[..., None])
x_inside = np.logical_and(x1[..., None] <= x_padded, x_padded<= x2[..., None])
contains_padding = np.any(np.logical_and(y_inside, x_inside), axis=-1)

# size of the sub-image
height = np.clip(y2 - y1 + 1, 0, None)
width = np.clip(x2 - x1 + 1, 0, None)
img_size = width * height

# find all largest sub-images
img_size[contains_padding] = 0
y_low, x_low, y_high, x_high = np.where(img_size == np.max(img_size))
cropped_img = tf_img[y_low[0]:y_high[0]+1, x_low[0]:x_high[0]+1]
```

The algorithm is quite inefficient; I am aware. What is interesting for this question is `img_size`, which is a `(50,50,50,50)` 4D-array that is ordered as described above. Currently I do:

```
img_size[contains_padding] = 0
y_low, x_low, y_high, x_high = np.where(img_size == np.max(img_size))
```

but with a proper argsort algorithm (that I can interrupt early) this could potentially be made much better.

Comment: This does not look like C to me...

Comment: Two algorithms come to mind: the merge algorithm from mergesort; and topological sort on the directed acyclic graph formed by saying cell [x][y][z][...] is adjacent to [x+1][y][z][...], [x][y+1][z][etc], [x][y][z+1][...], etc

Comment: @klutt Indeed. It is Python, because it is very short/easy to demonstrate the problem. I'm actually much more interested in the algorithm itself than the language-specific implementation. Once I have that, I can go and write the C code :)

Comment: How about telling `argsort` to use Timsort, so it does take advantage of partial sortedness? (Don't know whether the other algorithms do.)

Comment: Timsort sounds like a very good solution already. It's probably possible to do even better because Timsort has to find the sorted subarrays, while we already know where they are. But this would require writing a whole (complex) algorithm, whereas using Timsort is already weel-implemented.

Comment: @Stef I haven't heard of topological sort before. I did a brief google and it looks quite interesting; however, will the result be unique in this case?

Comment: Topological sort is about sorting elements when not all comparisons are available; in this case, it wouldn't sort the array completely, it would just find a generic way to "presort" it without actually looking at the data in it. So it would just find a "better" way to flatten an nD-array sorted along each dimension. So you could run it once, and use the result to write a linear-time function to flatten nD-array sorted along each dimensions, that result in a better pre-sorted array.

Comment: Is this just curiosity, or do you have an actual use case for this? If the latter, then what's your actual shape, and can you provide code to generate "realistic" data to benchmark with?

Comment: @superbrain I've added to the question how I've encountered this problem.

Comment: The linear search that you're trying to get rid of should be much faster than a sort that would let you get rid of it.  Just take the `np_max` out of the condition so that it's only evaluated once.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using parts of mergesort and a divide and conquer approach.
You start with the first two arrays.

```
[0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],//<- This
[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],//<- This
....
```

Then you can merge them like this (Java-like syntax):

```
List<Integer> merged=new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> firstRow=... //Same would work with arrays
List<Integer> secondRow=...
int firstCnter=0;
int secondCnter=0;
while(firstCnter<firstRow.size()||secondCnter<secondRow.size()){
  if(firstCnter==firstRow.size()){ //Unconditionally add all elements from the second, if we added all the elements from the first
     merged.add(secondRow.get(secondCnter++)); 
  }else if(secondCnter==secondRow.size()){
     merged.add(firstRow.get(firstCnter++));
  }else{ //Add the smaller value from both lists at the current index.
    int firstValue=firstRow.get(firstCnter);
    int secondValue=secondRow.get(secondCnter);
    merged.add(Math.min(firstValue,secondValue));
    if(firstValue<=secondValue)
       firstCnter++;
    else
       secondCnter++;
  }
}
```

After that you can merge the next two rows, until you have:

```
[0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7]
[2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9]
[4,5,6,7,8,9,10] //Not merged.
```

Continue to merge again.

```
[0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,9]
[4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

After that, the last merge:

```
[0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,10]
```

I don't know about the time complexity, but should be a viable solution

Comment: Ok, removed that part, was just a (quite bad) guess

Comment: do I understand you correctly that you would pick the last dimension (for 2D arrays, rows) and interpret them as 1D sub-arrays and perform a k-way merge on them, where ` k=prod(n1, ..., n(N-1))` (all but the last dimension of the array)?

Comment: I didn't do it on the last row, because 5 is not evenly dividably by two. I just do always merge two of the sub-arrays to a new one, and reduce it until I have only one left.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea: Use a min-heap with just the current must-have candidates for being the next-smallest value. Start with the value at the origin (index 0 in all dimensions), as that's smallest. Then repeatedly take out the smallest value from the heap and add its neighbors not yet added.